# What are differences between SQL queries?

Tags: sql, postgresql

We've this query:

```
SELECT t FROM articles t WHERE t.article_id = 59446
```

Also known as:

```
SELECT articles FROM articles WHERE articles.article_id = 59446
```

I can not understand

```
SELECT articles FROM articles
```

What does this mean? Why it works?

Update: table 'articles' does not have column 'articles'

Comment: Is there a column named `articles` in the `articles` table?

Comment: @Kevin No, table 'articles' does not have column 'articles'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a result of Postgres' object-relational architecture. For every table you create, there is also a matching [composite type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html) with the same name.

When you run

```
SELECT articles 
FROM articles
```

you are selecting a *single column* with the **type** `articles` from the table named `articles`. If you pay close attention to the output of that query you will notice that your result only contains a single column where the value is enclosed in parentheses, e.g. `(1,Foobar)` (if the table articles has two columns). If you run `select * from articles` the output is *two* columns (and no parentheses)

The same thing happens when you put the list of columns between parentheses:

```
select (article_id, article_name) 
from articles
```

also returns a **single** column with an [anonymous composite type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) containing two fields (this is also a good example that "column" and "field" is not the same thing).